# Xcode 4 C++ Project add file to build directory

Tags: c++, xcode, build, directory

I'm new to Xcode. How can I add a file to the build output directory? I have a `file.txt` which I want to open in C++.

The following code...

```
string line;
ifstream file ("file.txt");
if (file.is_open())
{
   while (file.good())
   {
       getline (file,line);
       cout << line << endl;
   }
   file.close();
}
```

... results in `Unable to open file`.

I found out that the executable is deployed to `/Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IAIK_CMS_Test-dfmszjneldfwjffsmjpmtiepyzej/Build/Products/Debug/`

I've tried to add the files in the project settings to the "Copy Files" in the "Build Phases". For details see this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhkIT.png

**Edit:** I'm looking for something like Eclipse's "add to Build Path" for Java.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Not answer but maybe it would be easier to not hard code the path and take it is a program parameter. Also argv[0] will be how the program is run, so you can load the file from the directory path. (so up to the last forward slash.

Comment: I'm no XCode expert, but it looks like you're copying it to `/usr/share/man/man1`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @111111, I thought about it but the problem is that it depends on the build mode you choose. For example when I build in debug mode the executable is deployed to `.../Debug/` in release mode to `.../Release/` and so on.

Comment: @molbdnilo, it doesn't change anything when I change the path there. I guess the "Copy Files" section is the wrong one for this issue. I added it to the question just for details.

Comment: Chris, so why not either read from `../file.txt` (the common parent of `Debug` and `release` or read from `/home/you/file.txt` (ie explicit/absolute path to your home directory).

Comment: I was trying to find a generic solution. As workaround I copied the files into `/Debug/` but the problem with this and your solution is that when you give the Main.cpp (where the code is in) to a friend and he compiles with an other IDE or g++ it wouldn't work as expected...

Comment: A copy files build phase is the right thing. You just have to get the path correct. There should be a special variable you can use to copy it to the build directory.

Answer (score 7):

Xcode5 is out, still no answer :)

For Xcode5 in C++ project settings, choose your app target, select "Build phases" tab, unfold "Copy Files" section, set "Products Directory" for Destination, leave Subpath field blank, uncheck "Copy only when installing" and add necessary file (file.txt) to the list using plus sign, like that:[image: Copy file on build]

And use "file.txt" path to access your file.